# damaged jpg: how do I recover it?

Tags: jpeg

I found on my disk some damaged jpg, they look like this:

[image: damaged jpg]

Any idea about how to recover them?

Here is damaged image file:

[image: damaged image file]

Comment: The file extension aside: are you sure it's even an image file? In bash, you can use `file myfile.jpg` to make a best guess.

Comment: And do all viewers (like: all your browsers) show the same? What is the file size compared to the number of pixels? (Looks to me like it's not recoverable, as your screenshot shows only a few different colors.)

Comment: I'm guessing this is the classic 8bits-reduced-to-7bits-due-to-FTP-text-mode error. If so, it's probably unrecoverable. Could you post the original file (not uploaded as an image, but just the file itself) somewhere?

Comment: added the image file, but I'm not sure it's the same image